# Write custom method getContentById(String id) in jaxb class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

First, I am still quite new to java (and code in general…) and *very* new to jaxb and xml parsing so sorry for any possible vocabulary mistakes.

I have a jaxb generated class called PropertyType like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PropertyType", propOrder = { "content" })
public class PropertyType {

    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if(content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

}
```

And an XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portfolio>
    <items>
        <item>
            <property id="firstname">John</property>
            <property id="lastname">Doe</property>
        </item>
    </items>
</portfolio>
```

As you can see, I need to check the value of the property's id to retrieve the content I want.

This has translated into a lot of `if` in my code, as there is a lot of information I need to retrieve for each `item` and additional controls I must apply according to the `content` found. Example:

```
if(propertyType.getId().equals("firstname")) {
    if(propertyType.getContent.get(i).equals("John")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

My problem resides in the fact that I need to implements controls that needs to take into account the value of two or more properties which I can't do with the code above.

As such, I'm trying to write a custom method in my jaxb generated class which would get the `content` of a `property` given an `id` I would provide.

I have tried to write it in different ways but often ended up with issues due to the `List<Serializable>` type of `content`.

What's more, when I tried to use my new method, I realized it was never taking into account the `id` I was using in parameter.

After researching for similar issues without finding a solution for my case I ended up writing this (very) not ideal code:

```
public List<Serializable> getContentById(final String id) {
    if(id.equals(id)) {
        return this.content;
    }
    List<Serializable> idNotEqual = null;
    return idNotEqual;
}
```

And it still doesn't take into account the `id` I am using in parameter, returning every content it can find.

What could be done so this method would take into account the `id` given as parameter?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Use a [`Map<String, PropertyType>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: So fast @CardinalSystem ! Thank you I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> And it still doesn't take into account the `id` I am using in parameter, returning every content it can find.

`id.equals(id)` returns `true` in most cases. You probably meant `this.id.equals(id)`.